# Error while creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I am Using:
jdk: 1.8
Spring webmvc: 5.1.11.RELEASE to run my project

While deploying a project facing error,

```
12:03:37,671 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) [spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:125) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:509) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76) [spring-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:209) [spring-webmvc-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) [spring-beans-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 32 more
```

Can someone hep me to fix the issue:

*POM.XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproj</artifactId>
    <name>testproj-part</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>5.1.11.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.spring-security-version>5.1.7.RELEASE</org.spring-security-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.selenium-version>2.39.0</org.selenium-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=10.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -->
        <!-- Oracle JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Activiti Workflow Engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.174</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
          <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
          <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
          <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
          <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HikariCP -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.usc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbcdslog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons file upload  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SFTP, SSH Client library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.50</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
            <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Selenium Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${org.selenium-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.selenium-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.selenium-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.selenium-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jamel.dbf</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbf-reader</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codesnippets4all</groupId>
            <artifactId>xss-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>sun.jdk</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>  
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security Filter Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <display-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Remoting service URL mapping -->   
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>remoteServerServiceExporter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>remoteServerServiceExporter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/remoting/RemoteServerService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

***servlet-context.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven>
        <message-converters>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>image/jpeg</beans:value>
                        <beans:value>image/png</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </message-converters>
    </annotation-driven>

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="2592000"/>
    <resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/" cache-period="2592000"/>
    <resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/static/" cache-period="2592000"/>

    <interceptors>
      <beans:bean class="com.test.testproj.springmvcapp.web.interceptors.RequestInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean> -->

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultViews">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Spring MultiPart Handler -->
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="1073741824"/> <!-- 100MB - 104857600; 1GB: 1073741824 -->
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Spring simple exception resolver -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="com.test.testproj.springmvcapp.exception.springmvcappException">error</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultStatusCode" value="403" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <!-- BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping for exporting Services using Hessian -->
    <!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
    </beans:bean> -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testproj.springmvcapp">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

</beans:beans>
```